# R - sjp.glm "Error: Unknown parameters: family"

Tags: r

I'm getting the following error when I try to plot predicted probabilities of a glm model using the sjPlot package in R:

```
Error: Unknown parameters: family
```

I'm somewhat new to R and have been unable to successfully troubleshoot this issue.  Here is code:

```
options(warn=1)
library(sjPlot)

df = data.frame(x = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80),
            y = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))

m1 = glm(data = df, y ~ x, family = binomial)
sjp.glm(fit = m1, type = "prob")
```

And when I run it...

```
> sjp.glm(fit = m1, type = "y.pc", show.se = TRUE)
Error: Unknown parameters: family
```

Since they both refer to "family", I would think the error is connected to this warning I get when I load the sjPlot library, but I don't know enough about R yet to understand it...

```
> options(warn=1)
> library(sjPlot)
Note: the specification for S3 class “family” in package ‘MatrixModels’ seems
equivalent to one from package ‘lme4’: not turning on duplicate class
definitions for this class.
Warning: replacing previous import by ‘grid::unit’ when loading ‘sjPlot’
```

Any help is much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug that occured when implementing support for more family types than just `binomial`. This bug should be fixed in [the current GitHub version](https://github.com/sjPlot/devel).

*Edit: it might also be to the ggplot update - which package versions of sjPlot and ggplot are you using? Perhaps updating packages might already help.*

Comment: I was using ggplot2 2.0.0 and sjplot 1.8.4.  After bringing sjplot up to 1.9 the problem was fixed.  Thanks!